# How can i save my push notification using sqflite and show the saved notification inside app using listview

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

#I was able to get my notification but i want to save all the notification using sqflite and show all the notification inside my app using listview or card..... i am new to this notification using thing and dont have idea how to save the notification and show it inside my app uisng listview or card i am stuck in this problem and cant get to find the right solution meaning i am able to get the notifications but now i wanna save that push notification uisng sqflite and show all the list of notification inside my app in a card view or listview

```
#this is in my main.dart

Future<void> backgroundNotificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundNotificationHandler); //mathi ko future lai call garaya ko
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

LocalNotificationService.initialize(context);
#this FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() comes on work when ever to show notification and when user taps it opens the app from terminated state
#simply saying app terminated state ma vhako bela notification send + app lai open garnekam garxa
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message){
      if(message !=null){
        final routeFromMessage = message.data["routeKey"];
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
      }
    });


    #this onMessage will only get called when app is in foreground meaning running but not in background

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      if(message.notification!=null){
        print(message.notification!.body);
        print(message.notification!.title);
      }
      LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });

    #this will comes in play when app is in background running and user taps on that notification and user is redirected to particular route

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      final routeFromMessage = message.data["routeKey"];
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
    });
  }

#This is my local notification

class LocalNotificationService{
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize(BuildContext context){
      final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher")); //we can pass icon
      _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: (String? routeKey) async{ //yo onselectnotification le chai app chalda faree popup notification aauxa ne tesma route dine kam garinxa aaba
          if(routeKey!=null){
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeKey);
          }
      });
  }

  static display(RemoteMessage message) async{
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecond~/1000;
      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: AndroidNotificationDetails("com.example.pushnotification","com.example.pushnotification channel",channelDescription: "This is our channel",importance: Importance.max,priority: Priority.high));

      //here payload show be described because above inside onSelectNotification we have given route and that data should be initialized in payload other wise we will get null route when tapping the popup notification
      await _notificationsPlugin.show(id, message.notification!.title, message.notification!.body, notificationDetails,payload:message.data["routeKey"] );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have an API to get all the notification from server ?

Comment: the above code I sent was an example on how i got my push notification from firebase cloud messaging from where i manually sent notification but now when i send that notification and get it i want to save that notification title,message using sqflite and show the notification inside my app using a card design or listview

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using LocalNotifications because `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen` will always give you notification whenever your app is in background,

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) async {
  RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
```

Use the above code so in **notification** you will have all the information of your data(title,body etc) from firebase, Now save this Data in your Sqlite Data-base or whatever you want to do with your Data.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will do as u say

Comment: can u look at the code i am trying to save data locally using shared preference